# what does it mean if sa_sigaction is set to NULL when calling sigaction()?

Tags: c, linux, unix, signals

What does the following code do?

```
struct sigaction saStruct;
saStruct.sa_flags = SA_NOCLDWAIT|SA_NODEFER|SA_SIGINFO;
saStruct.sa_sigaction = NULL;
sigemptyset(&saStruct.sa_mask);
sigaction(SIGCHLD, &saStruct, NULL);
```

In particular, what does it mean that `sa_sigaction` is set to NULL? Is this a complicated way to express something much more simple? I couldn't find any reference to this usage in the [sigaction man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html).

I'm primarily interested in answers for Linux (>= 2.6).

Comment: `NULL` might be treated as equivalent to `SIG_DFL`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NULL` happens to be equivalent to `SIG_DFL`; don't depend on this.

```
#define SIG_ERR  ((__sighandler_t) -1)  /* Error return.  */
#define SIG_DFL  ((__sighandler_t)  0)  /* Default action.  */
#define SIG_IGN  ((__sighandler_t)  1)  /* Ignore signal.  */
```

`SIG_DFL` etc. are intended to be assigned to the `sa_handler` member, but (and again, don't depend on this) `sa_handler` is on Linux in a union with `sa_sigaction` so assigning `NULL` to `sa_sigaction` is equivalent to assigning `SIG_DFL` to `sa_handler`.

```
    union
      {
        /* Used if SA_SIGINFO is not set.  */
        __sighandler_t sa_handler;
        /* Used if SA_SIGINFO is set.  */
        void (*sa_sigaction) (int, siginfo_t *, void *);
      }
    __sigaction_handler;
# define sa_handler __sigaction_handler.sa_handler
# define sa_sigaction   __sigaction_handler.sa_sigaction
```

Comment: Also from the docs sa_handler shall have those values assigned, and not `sa_sigaction`. It just happens to work under the current glibc because of `sa_handler`and `sa_sigaction`  are implemented in the same union. Doing as show in the OP's snippet is more then un-reliebale/-portable.